# Monaco editor in react app with language server for python intellisense

Tags: python, reactjs, monaco-editor

I have the python language server running on a port and now need to open a websocket in my react app to talk to the PYLS.

I'm using `monaco-languageclient`, and this line specifically fails compilation:

`MonacoServices.install(editor); //MonacoServices is from monaco-languageclient`

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/client.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'vscode' in '/node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib'
```

There shouldn't be a dependency to vscode, right?

This person found a way around it by editing their webpack settings, but to do that, I'd have to eject https://stackoverflow.com/a/56644955/3344422

Is there another way around this?

(I'm using this monaco library so I didn't have to edit my webpack config https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react#editor-instance )

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. I've set this aside as I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `customize-cra` to edit webpack config without ejecting, and provide it with a `config-overrides.js` where you `package.json` lives.

```
/* config-overrides.js */
const { useBabelRc, override, setWebpackTarget, addWebpackPlugin, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra')

//Monoco support for WebPack mode
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = override(
  setWebpackTarget("electron-renderer"),
  useBabelRc(),
  addWebpackPlugin(new MonacoWebpackPlugin()),
  addWebpackAlias({'vscode': require.resolve('monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility')}),
);
```