# Automatically modify webpack.config.js of react-scripts

Tags: webpack, react-scripts, react-app-rewired

I'm running a project by React, "@codingame/monaco-languageclient": "^0.17.3", "monaco-editor": "^0.31.1" and "react-monaco-editor": "^0.35.0". The compiling gave the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/common/client.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'vscode' in '/Users/SoftTimur/10Studio/frontend/node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/common'
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56644955/702977), and there is indeed `'vscode': require.resolve('monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility')` in `webpack.config.js` of [their example](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/16dd005ac8deb5f0072543ea4c80cee76643e31f/example/webpack.config.js#L40).

I then added `'vscode': require.resolve('@codingame/monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility'),` to the `alias` part of `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`. It did solve the error.

However, the problem is if I reinstall the project, I have to do this adding again. Does anyone know if there is an automatic way to inject `'vscode': require.resolve('@codingame/monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility'),` to the `alias` part of `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`?

PS: I'm using react-app-rewired already.

Answer (score 0):

The way we solved it. It not really elegant but it works.

You add a dependency called craco:

```
"@craco/craco": "^6.4.2",
```

Then you create a config :  craco.config.js

const path = require(`path`);

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        alias: {
            vscode: "@codingame/monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility",
        },
    },
};
```

Then in package.json you change scripts section as below :

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "craco start",
        "build": "cracox build",
        "test": "craco test",
        "eject": "craco eject"
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).